# Conditionally select dataframes from environment and apply a function

Tags: r, get, conditional-statements, global

I have a large environment where I want to conditionally select data.frames that has the string "ABC" in its name so I can apply a function to it. From what I understand, the last argument is incorrect, though I'm unsure how to solve this issue.

```
sapply(mget(ls(),.GlobalEnv),ls()=="ABC")
```

Comment: `mget(ls(pattern = "ABC"), .GlobalEnv)`